# Laravel: Telegram SDK not working with Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, telegram, telegram-bot, laravel-5.5

I have two project where I want to use [this SDK](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk). One is Laravel 5.4 the second is Laravel 5.5.
With Laravel 5.4 the message sending goes smoothly, but with the Laravel 5.5 I got the following error:
[image]

The code is:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\TelegramController;
.
.
.
TelegramController::sendNotification('contactMail', $params);
```

TelegramController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Telegram\Bot\Laravel\Facades\Telegram;

class TelegramController extends Controller {

    public function getHome()
    {
        return view('/');
    }

    public function getUpdates()
    {
        $updates = Telegram::getUpdates();
        dd($updates);
    }

    public static function sendNotification($type, $params){
        switch($params['subject']){
            case 'contact':
                $subject = 'Contact';
                break;

            case 'pricequote':
                $subject = 'PriceQuote';
            break;
        }
        switch($type){
            case 'contactMail':
                $message = 'New message from:: ' . $params['email'] . ". Subject: " . $subject;
        }
        Telegram::sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => 'mychatId',
            'text' => $message,
        ]);
    }
}
```

What's the problem?

**Edit:**

I forgot to add the lines to config/app.php (thank you, Mr. Pyramid)

Now I have an another error, that it don't find the `TelegramOtherException`. I reinstalled it, but still I got the error:

[image]

Comment: How did you install the sdk?

Comment: I placed `"irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk": "2.*"` into the `composer.json` than I ran `composer update`

Comment: check my answer and follow the doc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the docs you have mentioned, it suggests two ways to install sdk via `composer`

```
{
    "require": {
      "irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

OR Alternatively

```
composer require irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk ^2.0
```

Then afterwards add `providers` `app/config.php`

```
Telegram\Bot\Laravel\TelegramServiceProvider::class
```

and then `Facade` which is optional in `app/config.php`

```
'Telegram'  => Telegram\Bot\Laravel\Facades\Telegram::class
```

and at last publish it by any one of the following ways

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Telegram\Bot\Laravel\TelegramServiceProvider"
```

OR

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

REF : [Telegram SDK Bot](https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/docs)

**NOTE:** In Laravel 5.5 facades are automatically detected but still I recommend to do a cross check.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to add the rows in the app.php. Now I have an another exception, I edited the question with the picture of it.

Comment: have you tried these `composer dump-autoload` and then
`composer update`